# eclipse and perforce

Tags: java, eclipse, project, perforce

I have been trying for the best of a week but I can't seem to get a project added to Eclipse that then runs on another computer which gets it from perforce. Please can someone help or point me in the right direction?

I created a new workspace in Eclipse and added some external jars, do I need these in perforce or do the other users just copy them on their computer and update the build path?

The jars are updated often but have a name including the version name e.g. helper3.21.jar, if I renamed it to helper.jar would it still work? that way I could have them in perforce and just submit them each time a newer version came out with the same name.

Once I have my project in eclipse I used the team menu and added it to perforce but when I checked it out on another computer I couldn't get it to run as it said there were no previous launches. I created a launch config and checked that in but then I was getting a workspace name error.

Does everyone who checks it out need to make a workspace with the same name?

Can some one guide me step by step to set up a project check everything needed into perforce and get it running on another computer?

Thank you for any help.